# How to terminate screen while running a .sh?

Tags: linux

I search everyplace but didn't find a solution to my question, please help!

My situation:

I need run a huge .sh in my AWS (amazon web service), it will take about 4-5 hours to finish the job, I don't want to sit down just look those logs, so I create a screen to run it (screen 1), but while I configure the installation, I make a stupid mistake to create another screen and config and execute (screen 2).

The question is:

Screen 2 finish the job and I 'exit' the screen(terminated), but I can't terminate screen 1, because when I enter 'exit', it become a parameter of configuration, CTRL+A+K also din't work, please tell me how can I kill this screen, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logon to another session.

```
ps -ef  | grep yourusername
```

will show you the processes running  that you own.  The leftmost number is the pid of the process.

Issue a `kill` command on the process you want to stop.

```
kill [pid]
```

If that fails try

```
kill -9 [pid]
```

Comment: I tried this before but it didn't work for some unknown reason,but I tried it again when I see your post, and guess what?screen killed successfully.thank you very much,I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`KILL -9 <pid>` does the trick. If you want it to run in the background do it for the parent process.

Comment: how strange!I tried this before but it didn't work for some unknown reason,but I tried again when I see your post,screen killed successfully.Thank you very much,but I'd like to select jim macnamara's answer as accepted answer cuz it's more detailed.